# MySQL create table with condition on column

Tags: mysql

I want to create a customer table and want to restrict the SponsorID column not null if CustomerType=Guest.

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `CustomerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `WM_Status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `SponsorID` INT(11) NULL,
  `F_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `L_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` CHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `WorkNum` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeNum` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `CustomerID_UNIQUE` (`CustomerID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `SponsorID` (`SponsorID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `SponsorID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SponsorID`)
    REFERENCES `project1_team3`.`customers` (`CustomerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Please suggest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The published code is invalid in mysql because identifiers are quoted when the should be backticked if there at all and auto_increment column must be defined as key

Comment: @p.salmon there are problems here, but not the one you describe

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constraint like this one.

```
CONSTRAINT SponsorIDCheck CHECK ((`CustomerType` != 'Guest') OR (`CustomerType` = 'Guest' AND `SponsorID` IS NOT NULL))
```